# service bus for windows server 1.1 and windows azure pack service bus 1.1 same or different for on premises servers?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, workflow-manager, service-bus

Need a clarification between these two products.
Service bus for windows server 1.1 vs Windows Azure pack service bus 1.1

when i checked for service bus in Web PI, i could see only windows azure pack service bus 1.1.

But when i refer the [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4077554/add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-on-service-bus-for-windows-server), it is referring as service bus for window server 1.1.

Are they both same for on premises servers and I require this product in SharePoint 2013 combination.

Answer (score 0):

You should See "Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1. with TLS 1.2", this is what referencing in the article.

if you install the workflow manager 1.0 CU2, it install the `Window Azure Pack: service bus 1.1` But if you want to implement the TLS 1.2 then you need `Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1. with TLS 1.2`

Comment: our servers  have already setup with WFM 1.0 CU2 with Service bus 1.1. Now we required to  update TLS 1.2 so should we need to install 'Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1. with TLS 1.2' . Does this installation support on windows server 2008 R2?

Comment: i think, yes it is supported

Comment: thanks for response, can you please share if you have any microsoft support link on the TLS 1.2 support on window server 2008 R2.